# ggplot2 automatically removes missing values but does not rescale axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below show that `ggplot2` automatically removes the 2nd observation, and yet still keep the y-axis's range from 1 to 1000. How to make `ggplot2` scale appropriately without hard-coding the range myself?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA),
                 y = c(1, 1000))
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing rows with missing values in x before plotting?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(x)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

Or use `na.omit`

```
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

Comment: Ideally I don't want to hard code the `filter(!is.na(x))` because I don't know beforehand which variable will have missing values. Setting `limits = NA` does not work (Use this dataset `df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2),  y = c(1, 1000, 10))`

Comment: @Heisenberg How about replace `filter(!is.na(x))` with `na.omit()`?

Comment: Actuallly, I can use `filter_` or `drop_na_` to programmatically gives a string as a variable name, so the first solution does work. I'm still a little surprised that ggplot2 behaves like this.

Comment: I have updated my answer, removing the `scale_y_continuous(limits = NA)` approach.